# Combine several columns in one with Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have 10 columns and their values could be either null, or a name of a fruit.

I would like to add another column with all the fruits that every row has. I have used Concat(column1 , column2,..., column10) as name.

Issue : There are no commas coming on the result and if I add the comma before concatenating, we are having them together, the last word is also a comma.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard concatenation (||) in conjunciton with [COALESCE](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/_bj1shi28ac_2_shs3WgqA) function, which returns the value of the first non-null argument.

Example:

```
select coalesce(column1||',', '')||coalesce(column2||',', '')|| ... ||coalesce(column10||, '');
```

Comment: Thanks @pavel!
The issue is still the same. Using coalesce the issue with the comma still happens...